# Changing the picture to Identicon/uploaded picture doesn’t change the picture during sign-up process

Tags: bug, profile-picture, sign-up

Changing the profile picture to Identicon or uploading a new picture doesn’t change the picture in corresponding block (on the right hand side of “change picture” button) during sign-up process:

> [image: no Identicon in preview]